# Iterating many files and reading them with FileReader but is not workin

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to iterate multiple files and read them with FileReader and add to React State, so I have this code that It works when I upload one file, but on iteration it doesn't work even that it should, I get in the state only the first file but no all of them.

```
<input
className={styles.hidden_input}
type='file'
multiple='multiple'
accept='image/*'
onChange = {
  (event) => {
    const files = event.target.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const image = files[i];
      const reader = new FileReader();
      const randomizer = `${Date.now() * Math.random()}`;
      const images = [...data.images];
      reader.addEventListener(
        'load',
        function() {
          const img = {
            id: randomizer,
            name: image.name,
            stream: reader.result,
            type: image.type,
          };
          setData({
            ...data,
            images: [...images, img]
          });
        },
        false
      );
      if (image) reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    }
  }
}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this line:

```js
const images = [...data.images];
```

captures the *current* value of `data.images` which is probably almost always `[]`.

Because this is now always `[]` for each image being read,
when you spread it back into the state, you're doing this:

```js
[...[], img]
```

Which is overriding the images that were read.

To fix this, just spread the current value directly without capturing it:

```js
          setData({
            ...data,
            images: [...data.images, img]
          });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not working, I tried to implement that, but no.